# How-To edit part of a registry value

Tags: windows-registry

I`m looking for å way to remove last the 3 letters from a registry value.

Example:

*[HKEY_CURRENT_USER*\Software\Test]

"Setting"="**ABCDDD**"

I would like it to end up like this:

*[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Softw*are\Test]

"Setting"="**ABC**"

It is always 6 letters, and I want always to remove the last 3.
I prefer to achieve this using GPO.

Thanks!

Regards
Fredrik

Comment: This site isn't a script writing service, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

As it's pretty short, this might start you off:

```
$registryPath = "HKCU:\Software\Test\" #reg key
$Name         = "setting"              #reg value
$value        = "ABCDDD"               #default value if does not exist

IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath))
{
    #Key does not exist, create key and set default
    New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null
    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType String -Force | Out-Null
}
ELSE 
{
    #Key exists, read existing value and trim
    $strValue = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath).($Name)
    $strNew   = $strValue.SubString(0,3)
    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $strNew -PropertyType String -Force | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot "HelpingHand"! This will do the trick! :) Can I ask you one more. Let use say the Value was: XXXZZZYYY and I want to trim\remove the 3 letters in the middle, and end up with a value like this: XXXYYY    Would that also be possible with PS? Thanks again!

Comment: You could use the Remove method.  I.e. change the SubString line to be:
`$strNew  = $strValue.Remove(3,3)`
This will remove from strValue, the 3rd character the next 3 characters.  You can change $value at the top to be `XXXYYYZZZ` and then you will just have `XXXZZZ`

Comment: Thanks again - it works like a charm! One last question. :)  In a Value field, I always want to change 2012 with 2016. Like: \\servername\2012server\path\ -> \\servername\2016server\path\. Or it could be: TheYear2012WasGreat -> TheYear2016WasGreat . I just want to pick up 2012 from value string and change it to 2016.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to just use: `$strNew  = $strValue.replace("2012","2016")` for that case?